# Call sync nsurlsession inside async nsurlsession in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am trying to call a sync nsurlsession call inside async nsurlsession call and it doesn't work. Sync call doesn't complete. below is code.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL1"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    // Call first service
    [[NSURLSession.sharedSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if(data){
            // If first webservice is successful then dont call second service
            return;
        }

        // Call second service
        NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL2"]];
        [request2 setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

        dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        [[NSURLSession.sharedSession dataTaskWithRequest:request2 completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);

        }] resume];

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    }] resume];
```

Comment: Why do you want to transform async to sync ? Is it because you misunderstood how to use/manage async with blocks, etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Larme mentioned it's probably best to pass a completion block into your method here, then call it in the completion blocks of either of the requests (looks like you want to use the data from the first web service it it has some, and then the second if not):

```
- (void)webServiceRequestWithCompletion:(void (^_Nullable)(NSData *_Nullable completionData, NSError *_Nullable error))completionAfter {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL1"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    // Call first service
    [[NSURLSession.sharedSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (data) {
            // If first webservice is successful then dont call second service
            if (completionAfter) {
                completionAfter(data, error);
            }
            return;
        }
        // Call second service
        NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL2"]];
        [request2 setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [[NSURLSession.sharedSession dataTaskWithRequest:request2 completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (completionAfter) {
                completionAfter(data, error);
            }
        }] resume];
    }] resume];
}
```

Then you would call it with something like this:

```
[self webServiceRequestWithCompletion:^(NSData *completionData, NSError *error) {
    // do stuff with data returned from one of the two webservices here
}];
```

If this isn't what you're attempting to do, then you'd need to edit your question and provide additional context as surrounding how this code is called and why you have to use a semaphore (what it's waiting on?)

This site is helpful for understanding how to use block syntax: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com

And apple has some good documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html